# Problems with deploying in flask wsgi python2 on apache2

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my flask on apache2. File structure is following inside `/var/www/html/`

```
parsers/    
    app.wsgi    
    app/    
    __init__.py    
    init.py    
    static/   
    templates/
```

My app.wsgi file

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import logging
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/parsers/')
from init import app as application

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
```

My parsers.conf file in `/etc/apache2/site/sites-available/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 143.107.183.175:23580
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/parsers/app.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/html/parsers>
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm getting the page

> Index of/

What are the problems?

Comment: You have no ``ServerName`` directive in the ``VirtualHost``. Apache will ignore this whole ``VirtualHost`` if you have any other ``VirtualHost`` in the Apache configuration defined.

Comment: I added ServerName to the my IP

Comment: ``ServerName`` should not be an IP address, that will not work, and no port in it either. It needs to be a hostname. Use ``127.0.0.1.nip.io`` if you have no hostname, and then use ``http://127.0.0.1.nip.io/`` as URL.

Comment: I changed but it does not work.

Comment: Define 'does not work'? Same problem, different problem? What is the config you have now? BTW, your WSGI script file is suspect, as you should be updating ``sys.path`` before you try and import your application.

Comment: The same problem. I updated my wsgi file.

Comment: I put parsers.conf inside 000-default.conf. This solved the problem